# When exporting to Unity, my model's mesh is messed up. I've tried normalizing, but that doesn't seem to work

Tags: mesh, export

[image: Model in blender looks absolutely fine]
[image: This is what it looks like in unity. As you can see, the sides have been almost completely disappeared]
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to flip normals before exporting. In edit mode, select all faces and press ctrl+N

Comment: Note only that as of 2.8+ default keymap recalculating normals is Shift+N

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work, unfortunately. I think it might be an issue with the mirror modifier I've applied, but I'm unsure as to why the base of the object doesn't render properly either since I didn't apply anything to it.